# Importing two pyxb bindings with conflicting elements into the same namespace

Tags: python, xml, xsd, pyxb

I have several XSD files from which we have generated python bindings with `pyxb` (1.2.6). Each of these XSD files use the same namespace. Some of them define elements that have the same name (`MyNamedElement`). As a result, importing two of such bindings at once yields the following error:

```
pyxb.exceptions_.NamespaceUniquenessError: my:NAMESPACE: name MyNamedElement used for multiple values in elementBinding
```

I do not have to use two bindings at the same time, so it would suffice to simply clear `pyxb`'s internal namespace cache if thats possible.

Is there a way to do that, or some other python-magic to circumvent this problem? At the moment, my best idea is to use subprocesses, which perform the import and hopefully loose those again after finishing, s.t. `pyxb` will not complain.

Another question here on SO has the same error, but it turned out to be caused by a different problem: [PyXB: two versions of XSDs with same namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57219895/pyxb-two-versions-of-xsds-with-same-namespace)

Answer (score 0):

For those who are having the same problem, here is not the solution but a workaround. 
If the following imports throw a `pyxb.exceptions_.NamespaceUniquenessError`

```py
import xml_binding_a
import xml_binding_b
```

you can add subprocesses that handle the imported modules separately

```py
from multiprocessing import Process

def work_with_binding_a():
    import xml_binding_a
    # ...do more stuff here...

def work_with_binding_b():
    import xml_binding_b
    # ...do more stuff here...


p = Process(target=work_with_binding_a)
p.start()
p.join()

p = Process(target=work_with_binding_b)
p.start()
p.join()
```

Comment: Have you found a real solution by now? I'd find it kind of disturbing that I'd have to use multiprocessing for such a "simple" problem.

Comment: No unfortunately not. But I have not worked on that project for a long time, so I am not sure about the current state of the package.